# Calculate simple historical average using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'day':['1','21','41','61','81','101','121','141','161','181','201','221'],'Sale':[1.08,0.9,0.72,0.58,0.48,0.42,0.37,0.33,0.26,0.24,0.22,0.11]})
```

I would like to fill the values for `day 241` by computing the average of all records till `day 221`. Similarly, I would like to compute the value for `day 261` by computing the average of all records till `day 241` and so on.

For ex: Compute the value for `day n` by taking average of all values from `day 1 to day n-21`.

I would like to do this upto `day 1001`.

I tried the below but it isn't correct

```
df['day'] = df.iloc[:,1].rolling(window=all).mean()
```

How to create new rows for each day under `day` column?

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for an expanding mean:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'day': ['1', '21', '41', '61', '81', '101', '121', '141',
                           '161', '181', '201', '221'],
                   'Sale': [1.08, 0.9, 0.72, 0.58, 0.48, 0.42, 0.37, 0.33, 0.26,
                            0.24, 0.22, 0.11]})

# Generate Some new values
to_add = pd.DataFrame({'day': np.arange(241, 301, 20)})

# Add New Values To End of DataFrame
new_df = pd.concat((df, to_add)).reset_index(drop=True)

# Replace Values Where Sale is NaN with the expanding mean
new_df['Sale'] = np.where(new_df['Sale'].isna(),
                          new_df['Sale'].expanding().mean(),
                          new_df['Sale'])
print(new_df)
```

```
    day      Sale
0     1  1.080000
1    21  0.900000
2    41  0.720000
3    61  0.580000
4    81  0.480000
5   101  0.420000
6   121  0.370000
7   141  0.330000
8   161  0.260000
9   181  0.240000
10  201  0.220000
11  221  0.110000
12  241  0.475833
13  261  0.475833
14  281  0.475833
```

---

With replacing NaNs with 1 then averaging:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'day': ['1', '21', '41', '61', '81', '101', '121', '141',
                           '161', '181', '201', '221'],
                   'Sale': [1.08, 0.9, 0.72, 0.58, 0.48, 0.42, 0.37, 0.33, 0.26,
                            0.24, 0.22, 0.11 ]})

# Generate Some new values
to_add = pd.DataFrame({'day': np.arange(241, 301, 20)})

# Add New Values To End of DataFrame
new_df = pd.concat((df, to_add)).reset_index(drop=True)
# Replace Values Where Sale is NaN with the expanding mean
new_df['Sale'] = np.where(new_df['Sale'].isna(),
                          new_df['Sale'].fillna(1).shift().expanding().mean(),
                          new_df['Sale'])
print(new_df)
```

```
    day      Sale
0     1  1.080000
1    21  0.900000
2    41  0.720000
3    61  0.580000
4    81  0.480000
5   101  0.420000
6   121  0.370000
7   141  0.330000
8   161  0.260000
9   181  0.240000
10  201  0.220000
11  221  0.110000
12  241  0.475833
13  261  0.516154
14  281  0.550714
```

Comment: Why is the calculation coming out to be incorrect? For ex: 13th row in the output, shouldn't it be 0.5154?

Comment: Meaning, when we compute the value for day 281, I want all values from the past (day 1 to day 261) to be considered for its value. Similarly, when we do day 301, I want all values from day 1 to day 281 where day 281 is the recent value computed

Comment: Thanks, I will try. nonetheless I accepted the answer. But one question, isn't our 2nd approach very normal in real world cases? Meaning, we add a new record (with value), we expect to see a slight change to the subsequent value... So, am I right to understand that replacing `NA` with 1 is the normal approach? I don't really understand when shouldn't we replace `NA` with 1?

Comment: Full disclosure: I don't know, there may be a better way. But once you reach the end of the data the expanding mean will no longer change. You can try it yourself, no matter how many times you add the cumulative mean to the end of the series, and divide by the new length the value will not change. fillna in this case is used to give new meaning to each row, but it's an artificial injection. You could have just as easily filled with 0 to simulate a down trend.